# Item in ViewPager disappears and reappears when swiping back to page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**The Problem**

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 `fragments`. In one of the `fragments` I have 2 `Buttons` that I `setVisibility` to `VISIBLE`. This shows the two buttons. The problem is, when I swipe to another page and then back to the page with the buttons, the buttons are gone for a split second then reappear.

I can't figure this out, I would like the buttons to show permanently. If it means anything, I have the buttons drawn in the layout xml file with the visibility set to `GONE`. If there is a better way going about it, please let me know. Thank you!

---

**Fragment in Question Code**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

    /* Removed unnecessary code */

    // If this is the Negative fragment then add the buttons
    if(VIEW_TYPE == Constants.TYPE_NEGATIVE) {
        LinearLayout buttonsLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ButtonsLayout);
        buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Button addButton = view.findViewById(R.id.addThought);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNewThought();
            }
        });

        Button remButton = view.findViewById(R.id.delThought);
        remButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteLastThought();
            }
        });
    }
```

---

**ViewPager Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*
        Set up the ViewPager. Finds its view, sets up the adapter (which sets up the associated
        pages), sets up the necessary settings for it to work appropriately, and sets up its
        page ticker
     */
    // Find the ViewPagers and TabLayouts view
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
    // Define the ViewPagers adapter
    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Keeping all tabs in memory to prevent refreshing view. ABSOLUTELY NEEDED
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPagerAdapter.NUM_OF_TABS); // Equal to 3
    // Set ViewPagers adapter
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    // Set up TabLayout with View Pager
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove visibility gone from xml layout and in code do like below:

**Edited**

```
if(VIEW_TYPE == Constants.TYPE_NEGATIVE) { 
LinearLayout buttonsLayout =     view.findViewById(R.id.ButtonsLayout);
buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}else{
buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this when I get home. But that's doing the exact opposite of what I'm doing. Wouldn't that mean my other fragments will have a moment where they appear and then disappear?